# Drupal commerce how to create product bundle

Tags: drupal-7, product, commerce

I am working on commerce site in drupal7, I have installed Drupal commerce module and required module.
I have created two product type e.g. Product A and Product B.
Created two product under both type e.g. 
P1, Price 5$
P2, Price 10$
Now I need to create a bundle product 
For product P2 :
    If user purchase both product so bundle price will be 11$

I have installed commerce product bundle module but I am not able to create bundle of the product. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_bundle - says

Install the module as usual.

Setup some normal products.

Setup a product type with at least two product reference fields. Each reference represents a product in the bundle. Read more about product types, products and product displays at the drupal commerce userguide.

Go to the administer display tab, on the product type configuration screen and set the display formatter of all the product references you want to have in a bundle to the 'product bundle: add to cart form'.

Create a product from the newly created product type and reference the normal products as usual.

Link the newly created product to a product display.

I am trying to customize and unable to do the way I wanted...